# Checking if a variable is odd VERSUS adding a class in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to simply check if a button has been clicked using Jquery, the traditional approach is adding a class to the button once it has been clicked.

However I find this approach more simple:

```
var active = 0
$('.buttonSelector').on('click',()=>{
 active += 1
 if (active %2){
     console.log('Not active')
 } else {
     console.log('Button is active')
}
})
```

Is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: What I'd recommend is to set flag to be true on click, whilst flase as an initial value. Generally your approach is good.

Comment: You're essentially implementing a boolean with numbers. There's one potential issue with that code. Numbers are not strictly integers in JavaScript, so the expression `(active%2)` might have a tiny residue due to rounding errors.
Using a boolean would be the safer alternative: init with `var active = false;` and toggle with `active = !active`
Other than that not using classes, you lose the ability to style the button according to the state which might be bad UX. But that depends on the actual use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var active = false;
$('.buttonSelector').on('click', () => {
  active = !active;
  console.log(`Clicked: ${active}`)
  if (active) {
    //if active
  } else {
    //if not
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="buttonSelector">Click</button>
```

Comment: This looks much more simple, thanks!